# Line Model with Z-dimension

Tags: qgis, line, convert, contour, autocad

I made a contour model of a specific area and named it by its height. I need this Data to import into AutoCAD, so I saved it as .dfx with Information about its Z-dimension, by choosing "include z-dimension" in the saving options. when I now open it with AutoCAD there is no more information about the height. What is the way to keep the information in the dfx data?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the lines have the z dimension, or is it stored only as an attribute in the attribute table?

Comment: It's stored as an attribute in the attribute table, yes. Is there a way to get this values as an z dimension to use them in AutoCad?

Comment: I think the DXF export include z value only works if the geometry was created with a z value. In QGIS 3 the contour tool has a produce 3d Vector button so it can be exported to cad with a Z value.